# How to select and highlight feature by attribute

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, features, select, select-by-attribute

I have the below code which does a select by shape in my ArcMap how do I achieve this with attributes?

```
1. The map has only one layer 
2. There is a filter for the attributes on features
```

Below is the code:

```
private void ZoomToDGVSelection(int selectedRightID)
    {
        IMxDocument pMxDoc = ArcMap.Document;
        IMap pMap = (IMap)pMxDoc.ActiveView;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer layer = GetLayersClass.GetFieldBoundaryLayer;
        if (layer is ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IGroupLayer)
        {
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IGroupLayer groupLayer = layer as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IGroupLayer;
            ICompositeLayer pCompositeLayer = layer as ICompositeLayer;
            int layers = pCompositeLayer.Count;
            ILayer pLayer = pCompositeLayer.Layer[0];
            IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)pLayer;
            IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;
            IQueryFilter pFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
            pFilter.WhereClause = "RightID = " + selectedRightID.ToString();

            IFeatureCursor pFeatureCursor = pFeatureClass.Search(pFilter, false);
            IFeature pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature();

            if (pFeature == null)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This section doesn't exist");
                return;
            }
            pMap.SelectFeature(pFeatureLayer, pFeature);
            IEnvelope pEnv = pFeature.Extent;
            IGeometry pgeom = (IGeometry)pFeature.Shape;
            pMap.SelectByShape(pgeom, null, false);
            pMxDoc.ActiveView.Extent = pEnv;
            pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 
This for your WhereClause:

```
"YourFieldName = 'YourQueryFieldValue'"
```

i.e.
    " COUNTRY = 'France' ";

in your Example change your pFilter.WhereClause to:

```
        pFilter.WhereClause = "SomeFieldName = 'SomeStringValue'";

        IFeatureCursor pFeatureCursor = pFeatureClass.Search(pFilter,false);
```

Here is a more complete/complex example in C#:

```
//IQueryFilter Example

//e.g., nameOfFeatureClass = "parcels";
//on ArcSDE use ISqlSyntax::QualifyTableName for fully qualified table names.
public void IQueryFilter_Example(IWorkspace workspace, string nameOfFeatureClass)
{
    IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace;
    IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(nameOfFeatureClass);
    //create query filter
    IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
    //set the where clause
    queryFilter.WhereClause = "SUBTYPE = 'INDSTL'";
    //Execute the query filter
    IFeatureCursor featureCursor = featureClass.Search(queryFilter,true);
    //retrieve the results
    IFeature feature = featureCursor.NextFeature();
```

Then do whatever with the feature....

This code is from this example [On An Old ESRI support Site](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/componenthelp/esriGeodatabase/IQueryFilter_Example.htm)for ArcObjects 9.2, but it should work in later versions, Good luck!